# Proof of generalized Siegel's mean value formula in geometry of numbers

Tags: reference-request, lattices, euclidean-lattices, geometry-of-numbers

Let $\mu$ be the Haar measure defined on the space of unimodular lattices, identified with $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$.

The classical Siegel's formula in geometry of numbers states that for $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$, let $\Lambda$ be a unimodular lattice, and let

$$\hat{f}(\Lambda):= \sum_{v\in \Lambda\setminus 0} f(v).$$

Then $$\int_X \hat{f} d\mu = \int_{\mathbb R^d} f dv.$$

I wonder if there is such a generalization to this result:

For $g\in L^1((\mathbb R^d)^k)$, $1 \le k \le d$ and unimodular lattice $\Lambda$, let $\hat{g}^k(\Lambda):=\sum_{(v_1,\dots,v_k)\in \Lambda^k \setminus 0} g(v_1,\dots, v_k)$. I speculate there might be such a generalization of Siegel's mean value formula:

$$\int_X \hat{g}^k d\mu = \int_{\mathbb R^d} \dots \int_{\mathbb R^d} g(v_1,\cdots,v_k) dv_1 \cdots dv_k$$

Is this correct and proved somewhere in the literature? Or can anyone suggest a proof for it below if not too complicated from the classical Siegel's formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a generalization (roughly) exists, known as *Rodger's Integration Formula*.
See [Section 1.2 of Seungki Kim's Dissertation](https://stacks.stanford.edu/file/druid:ms598tw2644/thesis%20%281%29-augmented.pdf) for a reference.
Theorems 1.2 and 1.3 are of interest.

> **Theorem 1.2**: (Rogers). Let $k < n$, and $\rho : (\mathbb{R}^n)^kk \to \mathbb{R}$ be a compactly supported,
> bounded, and Borel measurable function. Then
> $$
> \int_{X}\sum_{\substack{v_1,\dots,v_k\in L\setminus\{0\}\\\mathsf{rank}(\langle v_1,\dots,v_k\rangle) = k}}\rho(v_1,\dots,v_k)d\mu = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\dots \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\rho(x_1,\dots,x_k)dx_1\dots dx_k.
> $$

Up to the requirement that one sums over rank $k$ collections of vectors $(v_1,\dots,v_k)$, this is what you want.
One can remove this restriction (to get the generalization that you want), but the formula becomes more complex --- there is an additional (additive) term on the right-hand side.
See Theorem 1.3 of the dissertation for details.

Comment: Thanks for this great reference! By the way although theorem 1.3 was proved by Rogers, the theorem 1.2 was not proved only in the German paper [17] by Schmidt in this thesis? Are there any other resources from which one could find a proof for theorem 1.2?

Comment: There's recently a proof of an [adelic version of theorem 1.2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.03138.pdf), which you can likely extract the proof you want out of. Kim claims [here](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~pthieull/LIA/Webinars/2022_05_02_Seungki_Kim.pdf) that Rodgers' original proof contains an error, though apparently it can be repaired.